# Weird and infuriating struts problem!

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I keep getting the following struts error:

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'dept': The requested list key 'deptList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

. . .

Here is the code in my .jsp file:

```
         <s:select name="dept" list="deptList" listKey="deptId" listValue="deptString" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select a Department"
         label="Select Department" />
```

Here is the code in my action file (which I have by debugging verifyed that it returns the correct values):

```
          @Override
          public String execute() throws Exception {
             org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener c = new                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener();
          EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean("employeeDao");                 
          deptList=dao.getDeptsList();                    
          //Employee employee=dao.getEmployeeforHRList(getLname(), getFname());  
          return SUCCESS;
          }
```

Here is the code in my data access file:

```
          public List<Department> getDeptsList(){
            String query = "from Department";        
            List<Department> departments = getSession().createQuery(query).list();
            return departments;
          }
```

Comment: I don't see any code in execute method that sets fetched collection into the form bean ?

Comment: This is the part of my struts.xml file that relates to this:

Comment: Sorry. . . hit wrong button:<!--This action is to populate the department list in the human resources page-->
        <action name="human_res.jsp" class="com.chreds.action.HumanResource">
            <result>human_res.jsp</result>
            <result name="none">human_res.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">human_res.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">human_res.jsp</result>
 </action>                                                                Do I really need a form for just a drop down list? There is no data being entered only displayed from the database.

Comment: how your jsp will find the data?

Comment: Guess I found out what the problem is. . . I have to write a form bean for the drop down menue :)  I was under the impression my above code in the struts.xml file would do it.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I have added the answer you can upvote& | | accept it :)

Comment: Okay. . . I am really tired. It is really late here; however, I am also using spring, which is supposed to be some sort of mapping system ( I am obviously rather knew to these technologies :)  . . . so I am figuring that I should do another bean in spring?

Comment: please check [struts tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html)

Comment: Tanks mon. This is one of the better tutorials that I have seen :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the list into formBean

You are looking up from jsp for collection and you don't have set that collection in the FormBean that or you can also set it in request/page/session/application scope with proper EL.